# Trying to install ubuntu 18.04 and keep getting error about grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install /target/

Tags: boot

I'm trying to boot from usb device and keep getting this error. I've tried to set up my own partitions but it didn't work. I don't try to dual boot. Please help!

Comment: Don't spend your time in 18.04. It will be EOL in one month.

Comment: FYI.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was the 2018-April release (2018-April is why it's 18.04) which had 5 years of *standard* support; thus that's 2023-April for EOSS... (*though it's been announced package upgrades will continue into 2023-May*). Are you only intending for this system to be used for weeks before retiring it...

Comment: I'd like to install 18.04 and then update it to 20.04 because I've got some issues with intel rst while i don't get them on 18.04

Comment: you need to edit your question to include what "issues" prevent you from installing 20.04 or better still 22.04 - the current and most up to date LTS version which might actually solve your issue. Do you really want to have more serious issues developing from an unsupported version?